# How to create a custom webview in Android?

Tags: android, webview

I have class (MyCustomWebView) that extend webview can i do something like this ?

```
<MyCustomWebView 
    android:id="@+id/myCustomWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

if not, could i do something like this.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView = new MyCustomWebView(this);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
    <your.package.MyCustomWebView android:id="@+id/myCustomWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Then in code you can do this:

```
MyCustomWebView myWebView = (MyCustomWebView) findViewById(R.id.myCustomWebView);
```