# How to use custom webview AND override functions?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

Bouncing off this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8599152/2607578):

I have made a custom webview called `FlingView` that incorporates gesture events. The strategy in the linked question above works fine for me; my activity layout xml is fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="net.brianclements.android.WebViewActivity">

        <net.brianclements.android.FlingView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:keepScreenOn="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_webview_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_webview_drawer_left" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_webview_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_webview_drawer_right" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

onCreate() does this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
```

and I've used this method to successfully load it:

```
mWebview = (FlingView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Now, the problem is when I try to override functions inside of it:

```
    mWebview = new FlingView(this, null) {
        @Override
        public void onLeftFling() {
            Log.d(TAG, ACTIVITY_TAG + "onFling left: ");
            someDynamicObject.thatCantBeUsedStatically();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRightFling() {
            Log.d(TAG, ACTIVITY_TAG + "onFling right: ");
            anotherDynamicObject.thatCantBeUsedStatically();
        }
    };
```

So how do I now insert `mWebview` back into the layout? The first casting method made it so simple. But from my research, I believe it now involves some combination of inflators, `findViewById()`, `addView()`, `removeView()` but I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View`s defined in your layout are instantiated in the `setContentView()` call, and you can't override class methods after instantiation. Swapping out the layout-defined `View` for your anonymous instance with the necessary overrides would work, but it's essentially discarding the instance created from the layout, and isn't really the cleanest way to this.

I would suggest another approach. Create an `interface` in your `FlingView` class that can be used to communicate those actions back to your `Activity`; very similar to an `OnClickListener`.

For example:

```
public class FlingView extends WebView {

    public interface FlingListener {
        void onLeftFling();
        void onRightFling();
    }

    private FlingListener mListener;

    public void setFlingListener(FlingListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void onLeftFling() {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onLeftFling();
        }
    }

    public void onRightFling() {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onRightFling();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

In your `Activity`, after finding your `FlingView` instance from the inflated layout, simply set an instance of the listener on it.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
...

mWebview = (FlingView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

mWebview.setFlingListener(new FlingView.FlingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLeftFling() {
            Log.d(TAG, ACTIVITY_TAG + "onFling left: ");
            someDynamicObject.thatCantBeUsedStatically();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRightFling() {
            Log.d(TAG, ACTIVITY_TAG + "onFling right: ");
            anotherDynamicObject.thatCantBeUsedStatically();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: This is excellent; and it taught me how to properly implement a listener. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the current FlingView with the one you just created you need to do the following:

```
CoordinatorLayout cl = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout_webview);
cl.removeViewAt(0); // removing previous flingview
cl.addView(mWebView, 0); // adding the new inflated one
```

Comment: I put those three lines right after my `mWebview` creation and was left with an all white activity where my side navigator panels and bottom navbar still worked, but no webview content was visible and no gestures were being picked up. I could see from the logs that it definitely loaded in the background though as it should, but it was just not visible.

Comment: Based on what you say I think the problem might be that view loaded webview has 0 height and 0 width so therefore is there but you can't see it. Try to set the height and width of your loaded webview to match_parent.

Comment: This answered my question. Setting `mWebview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));` was the missing piece. I did, however, end up using the other approach as it was a better designed solution overall. Thank you, @Mauro.